# Avoid if-else nesting using maps

Tags: c++

For example I have such a nesting

```
if (scale < 2 ) {turn = "First";
} else if (scale < 5) {turn = "Second";
} else if (scale < 8) {turn = "Third";
}
```

e.t.c

How can I avoid it using mapping, it should help me to use one if condition.

Comment: are the limits always equidistant (ie 5-2=3, 8-5=3) or is this just coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

You can even use a simple, sorted array:

```
struct TurnRank
{
    int rank;
    const char* turn;
};

bool RankComp(int lhs, const TurnRank& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.rank; }

const TurnRank kTurnRank[] = {
    {2, "First"},
    {5, "Second"},
    {8, "Third"},
};
```

This requires no dynamic allocations and is quite readable.

Now for the lookup, using `std::upper_bound`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void print_turn(int rank)
{
    auto first = std::begin(kTurnRank), last = std::end(kTurnRank);
    auto it = std::upper_bound(first, last, rank, RankComp);

    if (it == last) std::cout << "Error, rank " << rank << " too large!\n";
    else            std::cout << it->turn << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, something like this can provide the best performance:

```
// Predefined constants.
const char *scaleNames[] = {"First", "First", "Second", "Second",
    "Second", "Third", "Third", "Third"};
const int namesCount = sizeof(scaleNames) / sizeof(*scaleNames);

<...>

turn = (0 <= scale && scale < namesCount) ? scaleNames[scale] : "Unknown";
```

If you sure that `scale` is always valid, the checkage may be omitted, of course.

Comment: Direct mapping via array indexes can be a neat trick (e.g. here's a fine [demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOI1biZeD8) of this approach). It doesn't scale, or work for negative keys, though :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB It provides a good performance: O(1) instead of O(N) with direct iteration or O(logN) with binary search. It is easy to read. It may be combined with `static_assert` that will not allow you forget to extend the names array. Behaviour for negative keys may be changed easily. A good way in many cases, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, certainly a useful technique when it's appropriate, i.e. when your keys are dense.